# Barcode Settings in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-barcode

I am using jquery-barcode.
The following code works in a way:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/print.css">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../javascript/print.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="../javascript/jquery.barcode.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

    <body>

    <div id="bcTarget" ></div>   

    <script>$("#bcTarget").barcode("7100000000", "code39"); </script>
    </body>

<html>
```

The barcode displays but it looks like only part of the barcode. There are only 10 bars. But when I try the same number through several online 3 of 9 barcode generators, I get many times that amount of bars.

I saw some mentions of settings, but don't understand how to implement them given the current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After downloading the current version of JQUERY PLUGIN : BARCODE from

[http://barcode-coder.com](http://barcode-coder.com/en/barcode-jquery-plugin-201.html)

I was able see see a fully featured barcode using your code.  This site also gives a full description of the barcode api and examples of different barcode settings.

```
<script src="../javascript/jquery.barcode.2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```